# Intercom users have Enabled push messaging set to unknown

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, intercom

The users are not receiving the FCM Push messages and when I looked at the users attributes I found that they have the Enabled push messaging set to unknown.

Please note that there are some users that receive the notifications normally.

Did anyone face this kind of issue and what are the reasons that Enabled push messaging may be set to unknown?